# ES6 Class Inheritance Error Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have a GenericDB class to interface with Firestore, I want to extend this class to work with multiple collections:

```
export default class GenericDB {
  constructor(collectionPath) {
    this.collectionPath = collectionPath
  }

  /**
   * Create a document in the collection
   * @param data
   * @param id
   */
  async create(data, id = null) {
    const collectionRef = (await DB()).collection(this.collectionPath)
    const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

    const dataToCreate = {
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: serverTimestamp,
      updateTimestamp: serverTimestamp
    }

    const createPromise = isNil(id)
      ? // Create doc with generated id
        collectionRef.add(dataToCreate).then(doc => doc.id)
      : // Create doc with custom id
        collectionRef
          .doc(id)
          .set(dataToCreate)
          .then(() => id)

    const docId = await createPromise

    return {
      id: docId,
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: new Date(),
      updateTimestamp: new Date()
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I extend the GenericDB class to another class, I can not call the methods in the GenericDB class.

```
import GenericDB from './generic-db'

export default class OpenHouseDB extends GenericDB {
  constructor(userId) {
    super(`open-houses/${userId}/properties`)
  }

  test() {
    // I can call this function successfully
    console.log('test worked')
  }
}
```

Trying to call the `create` function defined in the GenericDB class which is inherited by the `OpenHouseDB` class produces the following error:

`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

```
  async setup({ commit, rootState }, property) {
    try {
      const { uid } = rootState.user
      const openHouseDb = new OpenHouseDB(uid)
      const { mlsId } = property
      openHouseDb.test()
      const createdOpenHouse = await openHouseDb.create(property, mlsId)
      console.log(createdOpenHouse)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

I've omitted some code but I've confirmed that calling `openHouseDb.test()` in the above code does successfully console log the correct string. I'm not sure why calling `openHouseDb.create(property, mlsId)` produces `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. I've confirmed that `openHouseDb` does have a `create` method but I can't figure out how to call it.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: What's the value of `property`?

Comment: The problem most likely extends from that fact that there is not a single `;` in any of these code samples. Automatic semicolon insertion is never perfect, and in code with this level of complexity (cyclomatic complexity) it is surely the issue.

Comment: @Barmar `property` is object representing the features of a house. I've confirmed that `property` is set correctly when calling `openHouseDb.create(property, mlsId)`

Comment: @Barmar the error is occurring on this line `const createdOpenHouse = await openHouseDb.create(property, mlsId)` in the last code snippet above

Comment: @RandyCasburn besides the missing `;`s does anything else look out of place? Otherwise should this code work?

Comment: _I've omitted some code_ - so there is no way of telling

Comment: I believe, after looking again, the error is caused by the ternary. I believe you must `await` for each independent call to `collectionRef`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn He says the error is happening on the call to `create()`, not on a statement inside the function. So it's never getting to the ternary.

Comment: Can you call `GenericDB.create()` without using your subclass?